# Why do I get the error no such column name

Tags: python, sqlite, input, insert

I'm writing a program to store credit card values as practice.
I keep getting the error "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: 
the table is created and the column: name. 
the column name exists in in the cards table in cc.db in SQLiteStudio
any help appreciated.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('cc.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def createTABLE():
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cards (                          
                       name text,
                       ccnumber integer,
                       exp_date text,
                       csv integer
                        )""")                 
conn.commit()
print('table created')


def entercard():
    ccname = input('Enter the name of the new card: ')
    ccnumber = input('Enter the card number: ')
    ccexp_date = input('Enter the Expiration date: ')
    cccsv = input('Enter the CSV number from the back of the card: ')
    c.execute("INSERT INTO cards VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?),(name, ccnumber, exp_date, csv)");
    conn.commit()


def printall():
    for card in c.execute('SELECT * FROM cards'):
        print(card)

createTABLE()
entercard()
printall()

conn.close()
```

Comment: You have a double quote in the wrong place in the first execute call.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot determine why you're getting that particular error, but you have a problem with the following line:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO cards VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?),(name, ccnumber, exp_date, csv)");
```

It is all a string. You need instead to separate the variables from the query string like so:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO cards VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",(name, ccnumber, exp_date, csv))
```

Answer (score -1):

I did the bellow in order to store values and retrieve them from the table.
You need to make the line look more like this.

```
    c.execute("INSERT INTO cards(name,ccnumber,exp_date,csv) VALUES ('Tom','new1','new2','new3');")
```

Space

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('cc.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def createTABLE():
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cards (                                                                                                                                          
                   name text,                       
                   ccnumber integer,
                   exp_date text,
                   csv integer)""")
conn.commit()
c.execute("INSERT INTO cards(name) VALUES ('Tom');")
conn.commit()
p=c.execute('SELECT * FROM cards')
j= p.fetchall()
print(j)
for i in j:
    print(i)
print(p)
print('table created')
def entercard():
    ccname = input('Enter the name of the new card: ')
    c.execute("INSERT INTO cards(name) VALUES ('"+ccname+"')")
    conn.commit()
def printall():
    for card in c.execute('SELECT * FROM cards'):
        print(card)
createTABLE()
entercard()
printall()
conn.close()
```